# Twitter integration with rails 3 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I want to login using twiter app for that i used gem 'omniauth-twitter' now please tell me whats app url in twitter when i want to use localhost:3000 i gave http://0.0.0.0:3000 as url

and in call back url my index page
like

localhost:3000/index
my app not able to redirect to twiiter page on click on this link
http://localhost:3000/auth/twitter

please some body help me .....

Answer (score 0):

For the callback URL use http://127.0.0.1:3000 as base and specify the route to the controller that deals with omniauth information.

Example: http://127.0.0.1:3000/auth/twitter/callback

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:3000  url gives not invalid url format please tell me about call back url

Comment: can u tell me a gud site for twitter integration using omniauth  i am following http://railscasts.com/episodes/304-omniauth-identity?view=asciicast

Comment: I you work with devise I recommend you http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-omniauth-part-1 and http://railscasts.com/episodes/236-omniauth-part-2. Otherwise for omniauth only : http://railscasts.com/episodes/241-simple-omniauth

Comment: i am also used devise and i am following railscasts.com/episodes/235-omniauth-part-1 but after create authentication controller and write method for index create and destry If  i visit /auth/twitter now and authenticate on the Twitter site we’ll see that we expect to get a large amount of information back. but i couldnt get any information its return me to device first page

Comment: Set your callback url to `http://127.0.0.1:3000/auth/twitter/callback` and set up the routes as in the rails cast to `authentications#create`. Restart your server to refresh the routes. I can't help you further, all is in the rails cast...

Answer (score 0):

I'm also using twitter-omniauth for signing people up with twitter... these are the routes I'm using in routes.rb, relating to twitter-omniaouth:

```
match '/auth/twitter/callback' => 'sessions#create'

match '/signin' => 'sessions#new', :as => :signin

match '/signout' => 'sessions#destroy', :as => :signout

match '/auth/failure' => 'sessions#failure'
```

Hope it helps?